# Why can't I execute libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, software-installation

I'm  a newbie in Ubuntu and I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. This week I've removed `libreoffice` packages (using synaptic) from my system because I understand that an upgrade of `libreoffice` would fix a bug which won't let me use keyboard shortcuts while in foreign layout.

After removing all my packages containing term 'libreoffice' I've downloaded the last version of `libreoffice`  4.1.4, (from Libreoffice site) unzipped it with archive manager and then typed the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in DEB folder.

the installations seems to stop in the middle without putting any icons on my unity launcher

I typed in terminal "libreoffice4.1" but it did not execute. this msg error appeared:

> The application cannot be started. 
>   [context="shared"] caught unexpected com.sun.star.ucb.InteractiveAugmentedIOException: > a folder could not be created

Below are the results of the output after entering `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`:

appreciate your help

```
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-base.
(Reading database ... 1086109 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libobasis4.1-base (from libobasis4.1-base_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-calc.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-calc (from libobasis4.1-calc_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core01.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core01 (from libobasis4.1-core01_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core02.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core02 (from libobasis4.1-core02_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core03.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core03 (from libobasis4.1-core03_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core04.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core04 (from libobasis4.1-core04_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core05.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core05 (from libobasis4.1-core05_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core06.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core06 (from libobasis4.1-core06_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-core07.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-core07 (from libobasis4.1-core07_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-draw.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-draw (from libobasis4.1-draw_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us (from libobasis4.1-en-us_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us-base.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us-base (from libobasis4.1-en-us-base_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us-calc.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us-calc (from libobasis4.1-en-us-calc_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us-math.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us-math (from libobasis4.1-en-us-math_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us-res.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us-res (from libobasis4.1-en-us-res_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-en-us-writer.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-en-us-writer (from libobasis4.1-en-us-writer_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) 
...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-beanshell-script-provider.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-beanshell-script-provider (from libobasis4.1-extension-
beanshell-script-provider_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-javascript-script-
provider.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-javascript-script-provider (from libobasis4.1-extension-
javascript-script-provider_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-mediawiki-publisher.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-mediawiki-publisher (from libobasis4.1-extension-
mediawiki-publisher_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-nlpsolver.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-nlpsolver (from libobasis4.1-extension-
nlpsolver_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-pdf-import.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-pdf-import (from libobasis4.1-extension-
pdf-import_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-presentation-minimizer.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-presentation-minimizer (from libobasis4.1-extension-
presentation-minimizer_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-extension-report-builder.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-extension-report-builder (from libobasis4.1-extension-report-
builder_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-gnome-integration.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-gnome-integration (from libobasis4.1-gnome-
integration_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-graphicfilter.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-graphicfilter (from libobasis4.1-
graphicfilter_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-images.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-images (from libobasis4.1-images_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-impress.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-impress (from libobasis4.1-impress_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-kde-integration.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-kde-integration (from libobasis4.1-
kde-integration_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-librelogo.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-librelogo (from libobasis4.1-librelogo_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-math.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-math (from libobasis4.1-math_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-ogltrans.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-ogltrans (from libobasis4.1-ogltrans_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-onlineupdate.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-onlineupdate (from libobasis4.1-onlineupdate_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) 
...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-ooofonts.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-ooofonts (from libobasis4.1-ooofonts_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-ooolinguistic.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-ooolinguistic (from libobasis4.1-
ooolinguistic_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-postgresql-sdbc.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-postgresql-sdbc (from libobasis4.1-postgresql-
sdbc_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-python-script-provider.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-python-script-provider (from libobasis4.1-python-script-
provider_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-pyuno.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-pyuno (from libobasis4.1-pyuno_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-writer.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-writer (from libobasis4.1-writer_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libobasis4.1-xsltfilter.
Unpacking libobasis4.1-xsltfilter (from libobasis4.1-xsltfilter_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1 (from libreoffice4.1_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-base.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-base (from libreoffice4.1-base_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-calc.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-calc (from libreoffice4.1-calc_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-debian-menus.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-debian-menus (from libreoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.4-2_all.deb) 
...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-dict-en.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-dict-en (from libreoffice4.1-dict-en_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-dict-es.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-dict-es (from libreoffice4.1-dict-es_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-dict-fr.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-dict-fr (from libreoffice4.1-dict-fr_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-draw.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-draw (from libreoffice4.1-draw_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-en-us.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-en-us (from libreoffice4.1-en-us_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-impress.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-impress (from libreoffice4.1-impress_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-math.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-math (from libreoffice4.1-math_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-ure.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-ure (from libreoffice4.1-ure_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice4.1-writer.
Unpacking libreoffice4.1-writer (from libreoffice4.1-writer_4.1.4.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-debian-menus (4.1.4-2) ...
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Setting up libreoffice4.1-ure (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core01 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core02 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core03 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core04 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core05 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core06 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-core07 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-draw (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us-base (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us-calc (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us-math (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us-res (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-en-us-writer (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-beanshell-script-provider (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-javascript-script-provider (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-mediawiki-publisher (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-nlpsolver (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-pdf-import (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-presentation-minimizer (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-extension-report-builder (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-gnome-integration (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-graphicfilter (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-images (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-impress (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-kde-integration (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-math (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-ogltrans (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-onlineupdate (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-ooofonts (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-ooolinguistic (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-python-script-provider (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-pyuno (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-writer (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-xsltfilter (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1 (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-dict-en (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-dict-es (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-dict-fr (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-draw (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-en-us (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-impress (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-math (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-writer (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-base (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-calc (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-librelogo (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libobasis4.1-postgresql-sdbc (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-base (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Setting up libreoffice4.1-calc (4.1.4.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
```

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and run `libreoffice`?

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get -f install"  or "sudo apt-get -r install libreoffice" something like that to reinstall libreoffice.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that only the icons are missing, everything else works?

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is just that the install didn't put icons on the desktop, not that it didn't install at all?

To solve the icons problem - in the file manager go to /usr/share/applications. You will find all the installed icons there. Put them on the desktop by right-clicking and 'copy to'. Select desktop and they will appear there.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to the installation instructions the install will place the icons for all  LibreOffice applications in your Applications/Office menu.

If you go to the launcher you should find the LibreOffice if you type it's name as follows:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. see my comment above to my original post